# Split exact sequences of vector spaces

Tags: homological-algebra

The question is on page 2, exercise 1.1.3.

For the proof that $\{ C_n \}$ is a chain complex I only need to show that $(i\circ p)\circ (i\circ p) = 0$ where $i$ is the inclusion map, and $p$ is the projection, if I am not mistaken this follows from: $ (i\circ p)\circ (i\circ p) = i\circ p \circ i =0 $ since $p^2 =p $ and $i$ commutes with $p$ or so I think.
If I am mistaken here, let me know how to change it?

I don't know though how to prove that every chain complex of vector spaces is isomorphic to a complex of this form.

The question from the book:

> Choose vector spaces $\{ H_n , B_n \}_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ over a field, and set $C_n = B_n \oplus H_n \oplus B_{n-1} $. Show that the projection-inclusions $C_n \rightarrow B_{n-1} \subset C_{n-1}$ make $\{ C_n \}$ into a chain complex, and that every chain complex of vector spaces of vector spaces is isomorphic to a complex of this form.

Comment: You should really copy the exercise statement here, preferably in a quotation block. Also, I'm not sure about the legality of linking to a copy of Weibel's book.

Comment: Iv'e added the question in quotation marks, hope you can help me with the question.

Comment: "$p^2$" does not make sense since the range of $p$ is not even equal to the domain of $p$. The answer is simply that $p \circ i = 0$. For the second part of the question, notice that you are working over a field (thus there are bases).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Why does $p\circ i =0$?

Comment: By definition... Just write it down!

Comment: So wait a minute is it right that $p$ commutes with $i$? As for to show this, I believe that we first have the inclusion $i$ goes from $B_{n-1}\subset C_{n-1}$ and then the projection of $C_{n-1}$ into $B_{n-2}$, why does it vanish?

Comment: If $p(x,y,z) = z$ and $i(x) = (x,0,0)$, why is $p \circ i = 0$...? I cannot do everything for you...

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks, I understnad it now.